# Swift 4.2 error dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_MDCSnackbarManager implementing ios Material Design's snackbar

Tags: ios, swift, material-design, material-components-ios

I'm trying to implement [material.io's snackbar for IOS](https://material.io/develop/ios/components/snackbars/),

I already install the it with cocoapods and I already imported it in my class by

```swift
import MaterialComponents.MaterialSnackbar
```

Then I run it and it's all good.

But after I implement it, it shows an error saying `dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_MDCSnackbarManager`

I implement it by

```swift
let message = MDCSnackbarMessage()
message.text = res.message
MDCSnackbarManager.show(message)
```

Answer (score 1):

make sure to update to a newer version of material components by using the command

```
pod update
```